# Memory overwriting while building an array of strings from file data?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

This is a homework assignment so I have a restriction that I must not use any square brackets (pointers only) in my function headers/calls. Inside the function I may use brackets to my heart's content.

The assignment is to read a baby-name from a file that corresponds to a year of birth. The file is organized so that the most common name from that year is first, second next, etc. The file displays each {name,gender,frequency of use} on it's own line  as shown : 
Mary,F,56009

Right now, I am simply trying to read these names from the file and place them into an array of strings (aka an array of char arrays) for later sorting. Unfortunately I am getting incredibly strange results. So far I have been able to manipulate it to :

increment the num_names var properly BUT when this works it continually replaces the name at the beginning at the list instead of adding it to the next char array available (as I am intending).

OR

to properly set the names to the correct pointers BUT when this works, my num_name counter will not move past num_name = 1.

I am not sure why these two are interplaying like this. I assume that I am misunderstanding something about memory. I have been to a tutor and my instructor and attempted to implement their advice but it always leads me back to the same problems. I have posted below all the code I have so far. However, the only functions that I am using at the moment are (besides main)

readAllFiles

readFile

processName

getFile

and compareStrings.

- I have tried passing the array as a pointer (*) and as a pointer to a pointer (**) and get similar results either way.
- I have many print statements for debugging - those are not necessary to the final execution.

Question: What am I doing incorrectly with my pointers / string array that is causing the memory to overwrite itself?

UPDATE : I can now get the names to read correctly in the 2-D array and my num_names to increment at the same time. The problem I had was that I was allocating memory either incorrectly or not at all. I used a for loop to go through my 2-D array and allocate both the rows and columns and that seemed to help with the overwriting. However, it now only reads the first file and stops at the first lane of the second file. Updated code below.

UPDATE 2: It was all improper memory allocation. See final code below. It works for the problem I was trying to solve. 
CODE :

```
    /**********************************************************************************
 * Most Popular Names -
 * This program examines baby name data contained in text files from the
 * years 1920, 1930, ..., 2010 (stored as name,sex,frequency) and
 * generates an excel file containing all female names that were
 * within the top 100 names for one of those years. The file will be organized
 * as follows :
 *
 * NAME : | 1920 | 1930 | ... | 2010 |
 * Ann    |  5   |  4   | ... |  1   |
 * Beth   |  1   |  2   | ... |  5   | etc.
 *
 * *********************************************************************************
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

#define MAX_NAME_LNGTH 16
#define MAX_NUM_NAMES 100
#define YEARS 10
#define FILE_1 "yob1920.txt"
#define FILE_2 "yob1930.txt"
#define FILE_3 "yob1940.txt"
#define FILE_4 "yob1950.txt"
#define FILE_5 "yob1960.txt"
#define FILE_6 "yob1970.txt"
#define FILE_7 "yob1980.txt"
#define FILE_8 "yob1990.txt"
#define FILE_9 "yob2000.txt"
#define FILE_10 "yob2010.txt"
#define OUTPUT_FILE "summary.txt"

 /* FUNCTION PROTOTYPES: */
/************************/


int readAllFiles(char **, int *, int); // called in main().

FILE *  getFile(const int); // called in readAllFiles().

int readFile(FILE *, char **, int *, int,  int ); // called in readAllFiles().

int processName(char *, int, char **, int *, int,  int); // called in readFile().

int compareStrings(char *, char *); // called in processName() and charQuickSort().

void quickSort(char ** , int *,  int ); // called in main().

// called in quickSort(arg1, arg2) for recursion.
void charQuickSort(char * , int * , char * , char * , int * , int *,  int );

void writeSummary(FILE *, char *, int *,  int ); // called in main().



   int main(void) {
    printf("begin : \n");
    int  ** all_ranks;
    int * rank_data;
    int num_names = 0;
    char * name_data;
    char ** all_names;

    name_data = malloc(MAX_NUM_NAMES * MAX_NAME_LNGTH * YEARS);
    all_names = malloc(MAX_NUM_NAMES * YEARS * sizeof(*all_names));

    rank_data = malloc(MAX_NUM_NAMES * YEARS);
    all_ranks = malloc(MAX_NUM_NAMES * YEARS * sizeof(*all_ranks));

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < MAX_NUM_NAMES * YEARS; i++) {
        all_names[i] = &name_data[i * MAX_NAME_LNGTH];
        all_ranks[i] = &rank_data[i * YEARS];
    }

    if (all_ranks != NULL && all_names != NULL) {
        printf("in main\n");
        printf("calling read all : \n\n");
        num_names += readAllFiles(all_names, all_ranks, num_names);

    //  printf("in main\n");
    //  printf("calling quicksort : \n\n");
    //  quickSort(all_names, all_ranks, &num_names);

        printf("in main\n");
//      printf("opening file and calling write summ : \n\n");
//      FILE * output = fopen(OUTPUT_FILE, "w");
//      writeSummary(output, (char **) all_names, (int *) all_ranks, num_names);
//      fclose(output);
    }

    free(rank_data);
    free(all_ranks);
    free(all_names);
    free(name_data);
    return 0;
}

/**********************************************************************
 * Accepts a pointer for list of names and a pointer to
 * the list of ranks to be used for the 2 - D arrays
 * to hold the file(s) data.
 *
 * PARAMETERS :
 * ************
 *
 * the_names - the pointer to the list of names.
 *
 * the_ranks - the pointer to the list of ranks parallel
 * to the names.
 *
 * returns the size of the list when the files have all been
 * processed.
 *
 **********************************************************************
 */
int readAllFiles(char ** the_names, int * the_ranks, int num_names) {

    printf("in read all\n");
    /* For indexing through the files. */
    int file_num;

    /*
     * For each file in the array of file names process the file
     * and add the names and ranks to the appropriate lists.
     */
    for(file_num = 0; file_num < YEARS; file_num++) {
        printf("in for loop in read all\n file number : ");
        printf(" %d \n", file_num);
        FILE * file = getFile(file_num);
        if(file == NULL){
            perror("cannot open file");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        } else {
            printf("else : FILE OPENED.\n\n");
            num_names = readFile(file, the_names, the_ranks, file_num, num_names);
            printf("NUM_NAMES in read all : %d\n", num_names);
        }
        printf("file_num is : %d \n", file_num);
    }
    return num_names;
}

/*******************************************************
 * Gets the appropriate file for analysis.
 *
 * PARAMETERS :
 * ************
 *
 * file - the file pointer for opening.
 *
 * file_num - the number corresponding to the file
 * in need of opening.
 *******************************************************
 */
FILE * getFile(const int file_num) {
    FILE * file;
    printf("in get file. file num : \n");
    switch (file_num) {
        case 0 :
            printf("1\n");
            file = fopen(FILE_1, "r");
            break;
        case 1 :
            printf("2\n");
            file = fopen(FILE_2, "r");
            break;
        case 2 :
            printf("3\n");
            file = fopen(FILE_3, "r");
            break;
        case 3 :
            printf("4\n");
            file = fopen(FILE_4, "r");
            break;
        case 4 :
            printf("5\n");
            file = fopen(FILE_5, "r");
            break;
        case 5 :
            printf("6\n");
            file = fopen(FILE_6, "r");
            break;
        case 6 :
            printf("7\n");
            file = fopen(FILE_7, "r");
            break;
        case 7 :
            printf("8\n");
            file = fopen(FILE_8, "r");
            break;
        case 8 :
            printf("9\n");
            file = fopen(FILE_9, "r");
            break;
        case 9 :
            printf("10\n");
            file = fopen(FILE_10, "r");
            break;
        default :
            printf("null\n");
            file = NULL;
            break;
    }
    return file;
}

/**********************************************************************
 * Accepts a pointer to a file,  a pointer to
 * the list of names gathered so far, a pointer to
 * the list of ranks, and the year (0-9) to which the file
 * corresponds.
 *
 * PARAMETERS :
 * ************
 * this_file - the file containing the names and ranks.
 *
 * the_names - the list of names gathered so far.
 *
 * the_ranks - the list of ranks parallel to the names.
 *
 * the_year - the year for which the file was created.
 *
 * list_size - the amount of names so far contained in the list.
 *
 * returns the current number of names in the list.
 *
 **********************************************************************
 */
int readFile(FILE * this_file, char ** the_names, int * the_ranks, int year, int num_names) {
    /*
     * PARDON THE MESS... STILL DEBUGGING.
     */
    printf("in read file \n");
    /*
     * For ranks 0 - 99 in the file
     * get the names associated with
     * the ranks and process them.
     */
    int rank;
    for(rank = 0; rank < MAX_NUM_NAMES; rank++) {
        printf("in read file for loop \n");
        char name_temp[MAX_NAME_LNGTH];
        char read_line[MAX_NAME_LNGTH * 2];
        int name_length = 0;

        fgets(read_line, MAX_NAME_LNGTH * 2, this_file);
        printf("LINE : %s\n", read_line);

        while(read_line[name_length] != ',') {
            name_temp[name_length] = read_line[name_length];
            name_length++;
        }
        while(name_length < MAX_NAME_LNGTH){
            name_temp[name_length] = '\0';
            name_length++;
        }
        printf("NAME : %s\n", name_temp);
        printf(" NUM NAMES : %d \n", num_names);
        if (num_names) printf("BEGINNING OF NAMES (in read_file) : %s \n", the_names[0]);

        // if the name was not already in the list, will increase the size variable.
        num_names = processName(name_temp, rank + 1, the_names, the_ranks, year, num_names);
    }
    fclose(this_file);
    return num_names;
}

/**********************************************************************
 * Accepts a pointer to a single name, the rank
 * at which this name was found, a pointer to
 * the list of names gathered so far, a pointer to
 * the list of ranks, and the year (0-9) in which the
 * name was found (for proper indexing in the rank list).
 *
 * PARAMETERS :
 * ************
 *
 * this_name - the name that must be processed.
 *
 * the_rank - the rank at which the name was found.
 *
 * name_list - the list of names gathered so far.
 *
 * rank_list - the list of ranks parallel to the names.
 *
 * year - the year in which the name was found at the
 * given rank.
 *
 * list_size - the amount of names so far contained in the list.
 *
 * returns 0 if the name was already in the list and some num > 0
 * if it was not in the list.
 *
 **********************************************************************
 */
int processName(char *this_name, int the_rank,char **the_names, int * rank_list, int year, int num_names) {

    int i = 0;
    printf("this name is %s\n", this_name);
    while(this_name[i]) {
        the_names[num_names][i] = this_name[i];
        i++;
    }
    printf("attempt to assign this name to the end of the_names\n");
    printf(" the names is now %s\n", the_names[num_names]);
    num_names++;
    return num_names;
}

/********************************************************************
 * Sorts the names into alphabetical order by first calling
 * a recursive version of this function using the values
 * defined herein.
 *
 * PARAMETERS :
 * *************
 * the_names - the list of names to be sorted.
 *
 * the_ranks - the parallel (to the names) array of ranks.
 *
 * list_size - the size of the list being sorted.
 ********************************************************************
 */
void quickSort(char ** the_names, int * the_ranks, int list_size) {
    char ** names_bck = &the_names[(MAX_NAME_LNGTH *  list_size) - 1];
    int ** ranks_bck = &the_ranks[(sizeof (int) *  list_size) - 1];
    charQuickSort(the_names, the_ranks, the_names, names_bck, the_ranks, ranks_bck, &list_size);
}

/********************************************************************
 * Sorts the name array into alphabetical order using
 * the quick sort method.
 *
 * PARAMETERS :
 * *************
 *
 * names - the pointer to the 2 - D array of names.
 *
 * ranks - the pointer to the 2 - D array of ranks.
 *
 * name_frnt - the pointer to the front of the list of names.
 *
 * name_bck - the pointer to the back of the list of names.
 *
 * ranks_frnt - the pointer to the front of the list of ranks.
 *
 * ranks_bck - the pointer to the back of the list of ranks.
 * ******************************************************************
 */
void charQuickSort(char * names, int * ranks, char * name_frnt, char * name_bck, int * ranks_frnt, int * ranks_bck, int size) {
    // copy pointers to the back and front of the lists.
    char ** tmpName_frnt = name_frnt;
    char ** tmpName_bck = name_bck;

    int ** tmpRank_front = ranks_frnt;
    int ** tmpRank_back = ranks_bck;

    // pointer variables for holding names during swaps.
    char ** swap_char = NULL;
    int ** swap_int = NULL;

    // loop control variable.
    char test;

    // find a midpoint for testing
    while(tmpName_frnt < tmpName_bck) {
        name_frnt++;
        name_bck--;
    }
    //loop control variable containing the value at the end of the list.
    test = * name_bck;

    // Set temporary pointers to traverse the list of names.
    tmpName_frnt = name_frnt;
    tmpName_bck = name_bck;

    // Set temporary pointers to traverse the list of ranks.
    tmpRank_front = ranks_frnt;
    tmpRank_back = ranks_bck;

    /*
     * Do the following while the temporary pointer to the front
     * of names list is less than the temporary pointer to the
     * end of the names list.
     */
    do {
        /*
         * While the temporary pointer to the front of the names list is less than or equal to
         * the end of the names list and the value at the temporary pointer is less than the value
         * at the middle of the names list increment the temporary names and ranks.
         */
        while(tmpName_frnt <= names + (MAX_NUM_NAMES * MAX_NAME_LNGTH)
                                                && ** tmpName_frnt < test) {
            tmpName_frnt += MAX_NAME_LNGTH, tmpRank_front++;
        }

        /*
         * While the temporary pointer to the back of the names list is greater than or equal to
         * the front of the names list and the value at the temporary pointer is greater than the value
         * at the middle of the names list decrement the temporary names and ranks.
         */
        while( tmpName_bck >= names && ** tmpName_bck > test) {
            tmpName_bck -= MAX_NAME_LNGTH, tmpRank_back--;
        }

        /*
         * If the first name is greater than the second
         * (closer to Z or z), swap the pointers.
         */
        if(compareStrings(*tmpName_frnt, *tmpName_bck) > 0) {
            ** swap_char = ** tmpName_frnt;
            ** swap_int = ** tmpRank_front;
            ** tmpName_frnt = ** tmpName_bck;
            ** tmpRank_front = ** tmpRank_back;
            ** tmpName_bck = ** swap_char;
            ** tmpRank_back = ** swap_int;
            tmpName_frnt += MAX_NAME_LNGTH;
            tmpRank_front++;
            tmpName_bck -= MAX_NAME_LNGTH;
            tmpRank_back--;
        }
    } while( tmpName_frnt <= tmpName_bck);
    // Choose recursive call :
    if(name_frnt < tmpName_bck) charQuickSort(names, ranks, name_frnt, tmpName_bck, ranks_frnt, tmpRank_back, size);
    if(tmpName_frnt < name_bck) charQuickSort(names, ranks, tmpName_frnt, name_bck, tmpRank_front, ranks_bck, size);
}

/* ************************************************************************
 * Compares two strings for equality. Returns a negative value if
 * the first name is less than the second, 0 if they are equal, and
 * a positive number if the first > second.
 *
 * PARAMETERS :
 * *************
 *
 * name_1  - the first name for comparison.
 *
 * name_2 - the second name for comparison.
 *
 * RETURNS :
 * **********
 *
 * a negative value if name_1 < name_2 (name_1 nearer to A or a), 0 if
 * name_1 == name_2, and a positive value if name_1 > name_2
 * (name_1 nearer to Z or z).
 * *************************************************************************
 */
int compareStrings(char * name_1, char * name_2) {
    while(* name_1 == * name_2 && * name_1  ) {
        name_1++;
        name_2++;
    }
    return (int) (* name_1 )- (int) (* name_2);
}

/******************************************************************
 * Writes the summary data to a .csv file for output to excel.
 *
 * PARAMETERS :
 * *************
 *
 *******************************************************************
 */
void writeSummary(FILE * the_file, char * the_names, int * the_ranks, int size) {

    if(the_file == NULL) {
        perror("in write summary");
        perror("cannot open file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else {

        char barrier[1] = ",";
        int **  rank = the_ranks;
        int index, name_lngth, count;
        for(index = 0; index < size; index++) {
            char ** temp = the_names + (index * MAX_NAME_LNGTH);
            while(** temp) {
                name_lngth++;
            }
            rank = rank + index;
            fwrite(temp, sizeof ** temp, name_lngth, the_file);
            for(count = 0; count < 10; count++) {
                fwrite(barrier, sizeof barrier, 1, the_file);
                fwrite(rank, sizeof (int), 1, the_file);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't narrow down the problem at all? Perhaps create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: I am almost positive that it is a memory issue. That is what all my print statements are for - to narrow down the problem. The issue is that sometimes if the pointer goes off into distant memory it just terminates my program. So I can go back to that last print and try to figure out what caused it, but right now I feel like I am going in circles. Fix one and another breaks down.

Comment: @chrk I tried separating some things as you suggested. I started a new project reading from one file using only my readFile() and processName() functions. When I run it, it reads the first two names but then says that the name stored in memory at the start of my array of strings is null.

Comment: `(int *) all_ranks` is very suspicious and perhaps the root of the problem?  With proper code, the cast should not be needed.

Comment: @chrk yes, I agree. I don't think it was part of the problem, though, as I am not using ranks at all yet. Maybe you are right and there is something I am missing? I partially fixed my problem. I will post my partial solution above and if you have any feedback as to how I can improve from there please let me know. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Suspect `int * the_ranks, ... int ** ranks_bck = &the_ranks[(sizeof (int) *  list_size) - 1];` should be `int ** ranks_bck = &the_ranks[list_size - 1];`  (pointer math).

Comment: @chrk I understand pointer arith. but I was playing around with stuff a lot when it wasn't working and I simply abandoned my use of ranks until I get the rest figured out. Therefore, many of it's states/behaviors are not ones that I intend to keep once I get my name array working properly.  I am passing the data back and forth but never using it or reassigning it. The functions that do are not ever called (yet - they are commented out). I have updated my code and my partial solution. You are helping a ton, though. Thank you so much!

Comment: You have comments from 2 different sources: @ chrk  and @ chux

Comment: @ chux oh my goodness! So sorry about that! thank you to both of you!

Comment: Minor: `for(i = 0; i < 100; i++) {all_names[i] = &name_data[i * 16]; }` --> `for(i = 0; i < MAX_NUM_NAMES; i++) { all_names[i] = &name_data[i * MAX_NAME_LNGTH]; }`

Comment: o.m.g. i finally got it. Thank you @chux for your patience and assistance. /long-distance high-five. /dance. :D

Comment: Note: `name_temp[name_length] = read_line[name_length];` Nothing prevents overrun of `name_temp[]`.

Comment: Note about latest change: For robust code, `malloc(MAX_NUM_NAMES * YEARS * sizeof(*all_names));` should be `malloc(sizeof(*all_names) * MAX_NUM_NAMES * YEARS);`  `MAX_NUM_NAMES * YEARS` may overflow as that is `int` math.  The second does everything in at least `size_t` math - certainly more range that `int`.

Comment: @chux you are right - just ran into a prob with that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code mis-calculated `ranks_bck`.

Pointer arithmetic strikes again.  No need to scale by `sizeof (int)` as the pointer arithmetic does that.

```
void quickSort(char ** the_names, int * the_ranks, int list_size) {
    char ** names_bck = &the_names[(MAX_NAME_LNGTH *  list_size) - 1];

    // int ** ranks_bck = &the_ranks[(sizeof (int) *  list_size) - 1];
    int ** ranks_bck = &the_ranks[list_size - 1];
    ...
}
```

OP had a number of issues - this was one.